# Modifying HTTP Request line in the HTTP request

Tags: android, http, httprequest

I have a `HTTP proxy` running as android service where i want to change the request URL from the header, But i am unable to find how to do it.

Suppose i have a HTTP request coming to my proxy like below:
`GET /index.html HTTP/1.1`

Then i want to change this request to:
`GET /index2.html HTTP/1.1`

I Have a android `HttpRequestHandler` class where i get all `HTTP requests`.
in the `handle` function of HttpRequestHandler class i get '`HttpRequest`' class object where i need to modify the request line but this class does not provide any functions/API to do so. I can see the requested URL by calling function `getRequestLine()` of `HttpRequest` class which returns RequestLine class object.

So anyone know how to change the request line of the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc reads ***abstract*** RequestLine getRequestLine() -- this means that you get some derived class (you may print it into the debug log if you wish). I think you are supposed to create a new instance of a class derived from HttpRequest and pass on that request rather than the original one.

Comment: SO you are saying i need to copy of received request whit modified request line. so this can be a solution but can i modify the original request rather than creating new copy?